# LibGDX: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6a581000 in tid 7616 (GLThread 7982)

Tags: android, libgdx, out-of-memory

I'm using Libgdx as you can see and when I try to get to a different screen I get this error in the logcat:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6a581000 in tid 7616 (GLThread 7982)
```

This is only happening to the device and not on the desktop emulator.

The screen I'm trying to set:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private static RunningGame game;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;


    private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
    private Viewport gamePort;
    private Hud hud;

    private TmxMapLoader maploader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
    private Runner player;
    private float dt;
    private boolean keyPressed = false;




    public PlayScreen(RunningGame game){
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("Runner_And_Enemies.pack");

        this.game = game;
        gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
        gamePort = new FitViewport(RunningGame.V_WIDTH / RunningGame.PPM, RunningGame.V_HEIGHT / RunningGame.PPM, gamecam);
        hud = new Hud(game.batch);

        maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = maploader.load("level1.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / RunningGame.PPM);
        gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2 ,0);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);
        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        new B2WorldCreator(world, map);
        player = new Runner(world, this);


    }

    public TextureAtlas getAtlas(){
        return atlas;

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    public void handleInput(float dt){

       if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
          if (!keyPressed) {
              keyPressed = true;
               if (player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 4) {
                  player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.3f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);

             }
                Hud.addscore(1);
            }
        } else {
            keyPressed = false;
       }


        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 0.4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2)
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-5.2f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);


    }

    public void update(float dt){
        handleInput(dt);

        world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);



        player.update(dt);

        gamecam.position.x = player.b2body.getPosition().x;

        gamecam.update();
        renderer.setView(gamecam);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.render();

        b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        player.draw(game.batch);
        game.batch.end();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
        hud.stage.draw();



    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gamePort.update(width, height);

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        b2dr.dispose();
        hud.dispose();

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
02-24 10:10:20.008 12792-12792/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
02-24 10:10:20.008 12792-12792/? E/Zygote: v2
02-24 10:10:20.008 12792-12792/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10233
02-24 10:10:20.008 12792-12792/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
02-24 10:10:20.008 12792-12792/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G925F_5.1.1_0041
02-24 10:10:20.008 12792-12792/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-24 10:10:20.008 12792-12792/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
02-24 10:10:20.008 12792-12792/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-24 10:10:20.038 12792-12792/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
02-24 10:10:20.038 12792-12792/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
02-24 10:10:20.038 12792-12799/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
02-24 10:10:20.038 12792-12799/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
02-24 10:10:20.218 12792-12792/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
02-24 10:10:20.218 12792-12792/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
02-24 10:10:20.228 12792-12792/? D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
02-24 10:10:20.228 12792-12792/? D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.mygdx.game
02-24 10:10:20.238 12792-12792/? I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.mygdx.game, Feature store :{}
02-24 10:10:20.238 12792-12792/? I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
02-24 10:10:20.278 12792-12792/? D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
02-24 10:10:20.318 12792-12792/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
02-24 10:10:20.418 12792-12792/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
02-24 10:10:20.418 12792-12792/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8455424
02-24 10:10:20.418 12792-12792/? D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
02-24 10:10:20.438 12792-12792/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher isFragment :false
02-24 10:10:20.478 12792-12792/? D/SensorManager: registerListener :: 0, MPU6500 Acceleration Sensor, 20000, 0,  
02-24 10:10:20.478 12792-12792/? D/SensorManager: registerListener :: 1, YAS537 Magnetic Sensor, 20000, 0,  
02-24 10:10:20.478 12792-12792/? I/AndroidInput: sensor listener setup
02-24 10:10:20.498 12792-12916/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-24 10:10:20.508 12792-12792/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
02-24 10:10:20.508 12792-12792/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
02-24 10:10:20.528 12792-12792/? D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
02-24 10:10:20.528 12792-12916/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-24 10:10:20.538 12792-12916/? I/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0x7f81633440 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = -2122624336 
02-24 10:10:20.538 12792-12916/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 8192
02-24 10:10:20.538 12792-12916/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-24 10:10:20.538 12792-12916/? D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [2560x1440]-format:1
02-24 10:10:20.568 12792-12881/? W/GL2JNIView: creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
02-24 10:10:20.568 12792-12881/? W/GL2JNIView: Returning a GLES 2 context
02-24 10:10:20.568 12792-12881/? D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [2560x1440]-format:4
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/GL2: all initialized 2
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: OGL renderer: Mali-T760
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: OGL vendor: ARM
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: OGL version: OpenGL ES 3.1
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: OGL extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_OES_texture_compression_astc GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_EXT_shader_pixel_local_storage GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_EXT_robustness 
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: depthbuffer: (24)
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: stencilbuffer: (0)
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: samples: (0)
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: coverage sampling: (false)
02-24 10:10:20.578 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: Managed meshes/app: { }
02-24 10:10:20.588 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: Managed textures/app: { }
02-24 10:10:20.588 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: Managed cubemap/app: { }
02-24 10:10:20.588 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: Managed shaders/app: { }
02-24 10:10:20.588 12792-12881/? I/AndroidGraphics: Managed buffers/app: { }
02-24 10:10:20.718 12792-12792/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1acaec3d time:207840769
02-24 10:10:20.828 12792-12792/? D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-24 10:10:23.168 12792-12792/com.mygdx.game D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-24 10:10:29.668 12792-12792/com.mygdx.game D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-24 10:10:30.558 12792-12881/com.mygdx.game A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6a493000 in tid 12881 (GLThread 8342)
```

How I set the playscreen:

```
 @Override
public void show() {
TextButton play = new TextButton("LEVEL 1", skin, "big");
    play.addListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new PlayScreen());
        }

    });
    play.pad(10);
}
```

I think it has with the memory or something because on my friends windows phone it's working fine but on my samsung galaxy s6 it's crashing everytime with this SIGGESV error.

Comment: Are you possibly calling `setScreen()` from outside the GL thread?

Comment: I don't know, this is how I call the screen:  @Override
    public void show() { TextButton play = new TextButton("LEVEL 1", skin, "big");
        play.addListener(new ClickListener() {

            aOverride
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new PlayScreen());
            }

        });
        play.pad(10); }    (also see main post)